# Manipulating PHP Objects (Deleting/Editing)

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a PHP object retrieved from MySQL.

I can retrieve the values for each object by going through a foreach loop and using the => operator. What I would like to do is apply some logic prior to the foreach loop and potentially to edit/delete some of the rows.

How would I go about changing the value of one of the items, for example question_id for object 1? Also how would I loop through each object and delete it if a certain condition is met? How do I then insert a new object?

Is there a tutorial somewhere that I can read, I can do most stuff with arrays but objects are new to me.

Thanks in advance.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [question_id] => 1 
        [question_type] => multiple_choice 
        [question_unit] => 7 
        [question_difficulty] => 56.5956047853 
    ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [question_id] => 2 
        [question_type] => multiple_choice 
        [question_unit] => 7 
        [question_difficulty] => 54.665002232  
    ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( 
        [question_id] => 3 
        [question_type] => multiple_choice 
        [question_unit] => 7 
        [question_difficulty] => 55.2923002984 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete object properties using [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

> It is possible to unset even object properties visible in current context.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

```
unset($array[1]->question_type);
```

---

If you want to loop through the object and manipulate it, you can use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [pass the `$obj` by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) using `&`.

For example, if you want to remove all `question_id` keys **if** it's equal to `3`, use this:

```
foreach ($array as &$obj) {
    if ($obj->question_id == 3) unset($obj->question_id);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to remove the whole object, you could do it like this:

```
foreach ($array as &$obj) {
    if ($obj->question_id == 3) unset($obj);
}
```

---

#### Update

It seems passing by reference does not work (at least not in your case), so you could try this:

```
$c = count($questions);
for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
    if ($questions[$i]->question_id == 3) unset($questions[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, if I use this code 

foreach ($questions as &$obj)
{

        if ($obj->question_id == 3){
            unset($obj);
            echo "done";
        }
}


Then I get a "done" echoed out. However, when I later reloop through $questions using a foreach loop the object is still there as it gets echoed out later?? Not sure what I am doing wrong. Do I need to save $questions once I unset the object?

Comment: What happens if you simply run this line (not within the loop): `unset($questions[2])`?

Comment: That works fine thanks - I'm guessing from the manual entry you linked me to, that doing it in the foreach loop only destroys the local variable.
Is there a way to unset the global variable from inside the foreach loop (stuff on manual page I can't seem to get to work) - otherwise I'm not sure how I can apply the logic I need to work out what to unset....

Thanks again for all the help

Comment: Added an alternative using a for loop

Comment: Thanks I think the new for loop works perfectly. Thanks for all the help!